# Cómo animar un nuevo elemento en un listview.builder?

Tags: firebase, flutter

Tengo un Streambuilder que obtiene datos desde FirebaseRTDB. Cuando se genera un nuevo child, la lista (alimentarList) se actualiza y quisiera tener algún tipo de animación que indique que ese nuevo registro ha sido agregado.

Intenté hacer uso de FirebaseAnimatedList, pero no me funcionó posible dado que debo trabajar con la lista (ordenarla) antes de desplegar.

El código del StreamBuilder hace parte de un StatelessWidget y tiene lo siguiente:

```
StreamBuilder(
                stream: alimentarBloc.alimentarStream,
                builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<AlimentarModel>> snapshot){
                  if (snapshot.hasData) {
                    final alimentarList = snapshot.data;
                    if (alimentarList.length == 0) return _imagenInicial(context);
                    alimentarList.sort((a, b) => b.fecha.compareTo(a.fecha));
                    return Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.grey[200],
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(bottom: Radius.circular(20.0)),
                      ),
                      child: Stack(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          ListView.builder(
                            itemCount: alimentarList.length,
                            itemBuilder: (context, i) =>_crearItem(context, alimentarBloc, alimentarList[i]),
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 10.0, top: 10.0, bottom: 20.0),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    );
                  } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                    return Text(snapshot.error.toString());
                  } 
                    return Center (child: Image(image: AssetImage('assets/Preloader.gif'), height: 200.0,));
                },
            ),
```

Cómo puedo animar un nuevo elemento en la lista?

Comment: Podrías intentar esto:
https://medium.com/flutter-community/how-to-animate-items-in-list-using-animatedlist-in-flutter-9b1a64e9aa16

Comment: Gracias @manuel. Es un buen artículo de AnimatedList, el problema que surge es cómo indicar que se agregó un nuevo elemento a la lista. Lo anterior, dado que la lista llega completa desde el StreamBuilder y no como componentes individuales

Comment: No veo mucha dificultad en hacer eso. Tú tienes la lista anterior que puedes almacenar en una variable y luego usarla en el ListView.builder.

Cuando te llegue una nueva lista "completa + nuevo contenido", filtras el contenido que ya tenías y creas una nueva lista solo con el contenido nuevo. Luego agregas esa lista. Esta solución debería bastarte si tienes un cantidad de elementos moderados entre manos.

Si por el contrario, trabajas con miles o ciento de miles de elementos, quizás no sea lo más óptimo, pero te podría valer mientras implementas algo mejor.

Comment: Mi lista si es muy grande, así que requeriría mucho procesamiento. Por otro lado, al ser un stream, cada que hay un nuevo registro, llegan nuevas listas. No tendría muy claro cómo identificarlo para guardar la lista anterior.